# MySQL select on results of previous statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm rather new to SQL I came across this problem:
I have relationship table where person has power

```
A has X
A has Z
B has X
B has Y
C has Y
D has Z
```

I want to select all persons with powers X and Y which is in this case B. Of course I will have a more complex power combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this,

```
SELECT person
FROM tableName
WHERE power IN ('x', 'y')
GROUP BY Person
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc618/1)

if unique constraint was not enforce of `power` on every person, you need to use `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT person
FROM tableName
WHERE power IN ('x', 'y')
GROUP BY Person
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT power) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link (*with duplicate*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc1a9/1)

Answer (score 1):

This is called [*relational division*](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/), here is one way to do this:

```
SELECT person
FROM Powers
WHERE power IN ('x', 'y')
GROUP BY person
HAVING COUNT(power) = 2
```